# @jdk.internal.vm.annotation.Contended didn't work

Tags: java, concurrency, false-sharing

I try to use @jdk.internal.vm.annotation.Contended with following class with java 17 and in Eclipse IDE it show "The type jdk.internal.vm.annotation.Contended is not accessible" this error. Can someone help me to solve this issue?

[image]

```
public class ContendedExample1 {

  @jdk.internal.vm.annotation.Contended 
  public volatile long count1 = 0;

  public volatile long count2 = 0;

}

public class FalseSharingMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ContendedExample1 obj1 = new ContendedExample1();
    
    long iteration = 1_000_000_000;
    
    new Thread(() -> {
        long sTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(long i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
            obj1.count1++;
        }
        long eTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(eTime - sTime);
    }).start();
    
    new Thread(() -> {
        long sTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(long i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
            obj1.count2++;
        }
        long eTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(eTime - sTime);
    }).start();;
  }
}
```

and when I run this program it shows like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
jdk.internal.vm.annotation cannot be resolved to a type

at falseSharingExample.ContendedExample1.<init>(ContendedExample1.java:5)
at falseSharingExample.FalseSharingMain.main(FalseSharingMain.java:7)
```

and when I run this with IntelliJ IDEA it shows this error

> java: exporting a package from system module java.base is not allowed with --release

Comment: This is a JDK internal annotation.  You should not use it.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @StephenC Thank you very much. It's for my learning purposes. these days, I study about concurrency and I try to refire this Jakob Jenkovs' YouTube video. https://youtu.be/tLS85IfsbYE

Comment: The typical approaches to prevent false sharing are:

1: super subclass padding (See JCtools: PaddedAtomicLong). 2 Store the fields in some array and ensure enough space between the items.  3. use offheap to control the layout in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name indicates, this annotation is for use internally within the JDK. It is not intended for general purposes. You cannot use it because it is not exported from the `java.base` module.

If your intention was to use this for documentation purposes, create your own annotation, or find a library that offers similar annotations. If your intention was to get the same effect has it has for Java internal code: you can't.

Comment: This just for my learning purposes. I try to learn about java concurrency and I try to execute this code https://youtu.be/tLS85IfsbYE

Comment: You don't need that level of knowledge to be effective with Java concurrency.

Comment: @KavishkaMadhushan If you're okay relying on internal private API, and you for some reason need to use `@Contended`, just use `--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.vm.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED` (replace `ALL-UNNAMED` with your module name if your code is in a named module). You'll need to use this JVM argument at both compile-time _and_ run-time.

Comment: @Slaw I would really advise against doing that. It is internal for a reason.

Comment: I would advise the same, but sometimes people have their reasons to do otherwise.

Comment: Slaw , Mark Rotteveel Thank you for the answers and advises.